# With the twitter gem, how do I retweet a Twitter::Tweet from Twitter::REST:Tweets.retweet?

Tags: ruby, twitter-gem

I have an instance of Twitter::Tweet, which does not have a method retweet.
( http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet )

However, Twitter::REST::Tweets does have a method I can use to retweet.
( http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Tweets#retweet-instance_method )

I can't find an example over at: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Any help appreciated. I've probably just left it too late at night to be figuring things out.

Cheers,
Ian.

Answer (score 7):

Ok. So, you only ever figure it out a few minutes after sharing how rubbish you are with stackoverflow :)

If you have an instance of Twitter::Tweet, and lets call that tweet, you can retweet it using the client.

So:

```ruby
@client.retweet tweet
```

Will RT the tweet.

I'll try and add this into the wiki for twitter-gem.

Comment: We normally don't like deprecation on SO but I personally love self deprecation ;)

Comment: I find that 8pm when coding, the thought process is "I know I'm doing something wrong and stupid. But what?" By 1am, it's certainly even more self-depracting, and seeking last resorts like SO.